# dictionary with regex matches as key and their number of frequency as the value

Tags: python, regex, string, dictionary

I am new to python and i am trying to match something with regex and then create a dictionary with the match as the key and the number of occurrence as the value, but i'm not sure how to do it on a pythonic way.

```
import re
st = 'I like football . I like Basketball. I like cricket. I like football'
reg = "I like (\w+)"
d = {}
match = re.findall(reg, st, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Desired output for d would be this :

```
{football:2, basketball:1, cricket:1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any imports:

```
import re
st = 'I like football . I like Basketball. I like cricket. I like football'
reg = "I like (\w+)"
d = {}
match = re.findall(reg, st, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

freq = {}
for i in match:
    if i in freq:
        freq[i] += 1
    else:
        freq[i] = 1
print(freq)
>>> {'football': 2, 'Basketball': 1, 'cricket': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
print (Counter(match))
#Counter({'football': 2, 'Basketball': 1, 'cricket': 1})
```